# How can I make the outputs of a genrule selectively visible?

Tags: bazel

Suppose I have a genrule that generates multiple outputs:

```
genrule(
    name = "gen",
    outs = ["a", "b"],
    ...,
)
```

How can I give `a` public visibility but not `b`?

Some things I have tried that don't work:

- `visibility = ["//visibility:public"]` on the `genrule` makes both `a` and `b` public.
- `exports_files(["a"])` produces an error that the "generated label ... conflicts with existing generated file".

Comment: Using an alias or filegroup as answered below is the answer, but note also that if you don't need `b`, you don't have to list it in the `outs`. Bazel will ignore it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not directly; the visibility of the `genrule` is the visibility of its outputs. However, you could make the `genrule` target private and add a public `alias` or `filegroup` for `a`:

```
genrule(
   name = "g",
   outs = ["a", "b"],
)
alias(
   name = "a-public",
   actual = ":a",
   visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
filegroup(
   name = "multiple-public",
   srcs = [":a", ":b"],
   visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
```

Comment: A filegroup would also work if there are multiple files you want to make public while leaving others private